# When using await does it block the function it is used in?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have this `async` function below:

```
async LoadEditForm() {
    const { default : EditHero } = await import('./EditHero');
    this.setState({ lazyEditHero: EditHero })
}
```

And it is called it here:

```
handleEnableAddMode = async () => {
    await this.LoadEditForm();
    this.setState({
        addingHero: true,
        selectedHero: { id: '', name: '', saying: '' }
    });
}
```

I have a question regarding the code above:

1. At this line: `await this.LoadEditForm();` in the `handleEnableAddMode` function, does it block that function? In other words does the `this.setState(...)` function get called immediately or does it wait for the `await` call to finish.

   - Since I heard people saying the `async/await` concept is to allow you to write async code in a synchronous manner. That is kind of confusing me. Can someone clarify?

Comment: Why are you using await at all?  None of this code looks like it's async nor using promises.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Would this be a better way: Inside of the `LoadEditForm` instead of doing `const { default : EditHero } = await import('./EditHero');` do `import('./EditHero').then(({default: EditHero}) => {this.setState(...)}).catch(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At this line: await this.LoadEditForm(); in the handleEnableAddMode function, does it block that function? In other words does the this.setState(...) function get called immediately or does it wait for the await call to finish.

One of those is not the other one "in other words".

It doesn't block, it waits. The control will return to the caller of the async function. When the promise being waited on is resolved or rejected, then the waiting function will resume.

https://jsfiddle.net/7yxhqoo4/ has a simple example, thus:

```
function resolveAfterHalfSecond() { 
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 500);
  });
}

async function f1() {
  $("div").append("<p>before await</p>");
  await resolveAfterHalfSecond();
  $("div").append("<p>after await</p>");
}

function test()
{
  $("div").append("<p>before call async function</p>");
  f1();
  $("div").append("<p>after call async function</p>");
}

$(test);
```

The immediate output looks like:

> before call async function
>
> before await
>
> after call async function

And after half a second, it looks like

> before call async function
>
> before await
>
> after call async function
>
> after await.

When the `await` was hit in `f1()` it didn't block, but immediately went back to `test()` and finished that function. When the promise was resolved, `f1()` resumed.

Comment: Ohh this example helped cleared it up a lot. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Typically `await` will hold until it receives either a successful result because the promise was "resolved", or it encounters an error because the promise was "rejected".

If neither of these two events occur, your promise is broken and the `await` may never complete.

Answer (score 1):

When you're calling an Asyc function, it will return a promise, whenever you return a value in your async function your promise will be resolved, and if you throw an exception, your promise is rejected. On the other side, the `await` expression pauses the execution of the async function and waits for the passed Promise's resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and returns the resolved value.

Based on the provided samples in Mozile documentations:

```
function getProcessedData(url) {
  return downloadData(url) // returns a promise
    .catch(e => {
      return downloadFallbackData(url)  // returns a promise
    })
    .then(v => {
      return processDataInWorker(v); // returns a promise
    });
}


async function getProcessedData(url) {
  let v;
  try {
    v = await downloadData(url); 
  } catch(e) {
    v = await downloadFallbackData(url);
  }
  return processDataInWorker(v);
}
```

In your case, your setState won't be executed until your `await this.LoadEditForm();` be fulfilled. But the thing is you've not `catch` the probable rejection of your promise. So if the function b rejected, your setState will be executed anyway.

So you have to wrap the await function and the following lines in a `try ... catch` statement.

Comment: Ah ok I see. When you say `"you've not catch the probable rejection of your promise"`. The thing in this case is that the `LoadEditForm` async function doesn't return a `Promise` at all. So even if I put `this.LoadEditForm();` into a `try ... catch` it will not catch the rejection. So I would have to return a `Promise` OR some value from `LoadEditForm` async function correct?

Comment: By default an Async function is a promise by itself, you just need to return some values or throw an exception in order to retrieve the function status.